# Cell text colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am somehow having problems with something as simple as setting text colour with

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor lightTextColor];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    }
    NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:messagingArrayToBeDisplayedInTableWhenCalloutTapped[indexPath.row]];

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor lightTextColor];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:1];


    return cell;
}
```

The background colour works, but setting text colour to whiteColor has no effect so both the title and subtitle are a default grey colour. I have tried changing colours in my prototype cell, but that also did not work. Is anyone able to suggest a solution? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? If so, you can also change it there.

Comment: You can delete 6 lines of code, because `cell` is _never_ nil.

Comment: I've changed the label colour in attributes inspector, but nothing happens

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. Of course I had to make up some text because I don't have your array. Also I had to change clearColor to blackColor because otherwise the text was white on a white background and I couldn't see it! :) Anyway, since I can't reproduce the problem, that proves that _other_ code that you have not shown is causing it. Thus you have not given enough information to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:  always returns a valid cell, there fore cell is never nil and that code is never executed.

So remove that condition and see if it works.